# ANTD in React + Typescript throws error saying my array of object rules are not of type Rule[] in Select Multiple

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, antd

guys. I am here looking for help because I am using ANTD in React+TS, and when I want to pass an Array of rules objects, the console throws an error stating my rules array is not of type Rule[].

the error goes as follows:

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { required?: boolean | undefined; prefixCls?: string | undefined; className?: string | undefined; style?: CSSProperties | undefined; id?: string | undefined; ... 34 more ...; help?: ReactNode; } & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.

```
Type '({ required: boolean; message: string; type?: undefined; } | { required: number; message: string; type: string; })[]' is not assignable to type 'Rule[]'.
```

Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<FormItemInterface, any, {}, never, FormItemInterface, FormItemInterface>): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.

```
Type '({ required: boolean; message: string; type?: undefined; } | { required: number; message: string; type: string; })[]' is not assignable to type 'Rule[]'.
```

I have this variable as rules:

```
    selectMultiple: [
  { required: true, message: 'This field is required' },
  {
    required: 5,
    message: 'Field must have at least 1 and at most 5 items',
    type: 'array',
  },
],
```

I have tracked the error to the second object, because with only the required object it works ok, however, the second one, breaks it.

and this is my JSX Template where I am using the rules prop:

```
   <Form.Item
            label={t('positions.form.niceToHave')}
            name="niceToHave"
            rules={rules.selectMultiple}
          >
            <Select
              width="100%"
              mode="multiple"
              placeholder={t('positions.form.niceToHave')}
            >
              {fields?.skills?.map((skill) => (
                <Select.Option key={skill.id} value={skill.sKillName}>
                  {skill.sKillName}
                </Select.Option>
              ))}
            </Select>
          </Form.Item>
```

Comment: An off topic comment but why is `k` in `sKillName` capitalised?

Comment: Question: is this variable `rules.selectMultiple` dynamic or static?

Comment: Rajesh, yes, it's like that, the backend guys misspelled it. 

It's static, it's basically my object config but for rules.

I have a parent object for my rules.

eg:

const parentObjectRules = {
rules1: [. . .],
rules2: [. . .],
rules3: [. . .]
}